# Get variable value from an object - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am trying to get variable value from an object in jquery but its returning undefined.

```
console.log(itemName.name);
```

Returns: unidentified

Code:

```
 console.log(itemName);
```

Object:

[image]

I need the value of the name variable, don't know the exact syntax to grab it from the object.

Comment: You need to post actual code in your question. Not some postage stamp sized blurry image. See [mcve]

Comment: itemName is the object, -L0uwNe[...] is the first child, name is the second child. Will be itemName.-L0uwNe[...].name

Comment: @Roy first child name is unknown, I can't hard code this.

Comment: try itemName.[0].name or itemName[0].name

Comment: Already tried, returns unidentified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get the first child first then get the `name` like :

```
itemName["-L0uwNE54j88Gu15iuRD"].name
```

If the first child name is unknown you could use `Object.keys()` to get it:

```
var first_child_name = Object.keys(itemName)[0];
itemName[first_child_name].name
```

---

```js
var itemName = {
  "-L0uwNE54j88Gu15iuRD": {
    id: 1,
    name: "Cakes"
  }
}

console.log(itemName["-L0uwNE54j88Gu15iuRD"].name);
console.log(itemName[Object.keys(itemName)[0]].name);
```

Comment: First child name is unknown, I can't hard code this.

Comment: Check my update..

Comment: Or the duplicate

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Thank you, it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the purpose:

itemName.-L0uwNE54j88Gu15iuRD.name